# Combining HTML code with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this code with PHP and HTML but I cant seem to get the PHP code to echo into the HTML.

```
<?php

countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);

function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
$the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
$today=time();
$difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
$days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minutes";?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Callum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the variables `$days` etc inside a function, but are expecting to access them outside that functions. This cannot be done, as the variables do not have the correct [*scope*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

The smallest change you can make to see it work is this:

```
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
    global $days, $hours, $minutes; // ADD THIS
    $the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
    $today=time();
    $difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
    $days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
    $hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
    $minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
}
```

This works because it makes your variables have *global scope*. **However, it's the wrong solution.**

The better solution would be to have your function *return* the values you need -- and since there are three values but only one return, do so with an array:

```
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
    $the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
    $today=time();
    $difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
    $days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
    $hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
    $minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
    return array($days, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

And then, call the function and retrieve the values like this:

```
list($days, $hours, $minutes) = countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);
```

There are many variations on the "return multiple values in an array" theme; I have used the shortest (but perhaps not the most clear, because it uses [`list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)) here.

Comment: @Jon - Please bold the "However" sentence. :)

Comment: I´m pretty sure your first solution does not work. You need to declare your variables outside the function as well, just using `global` is not enough. But your second solution is better anyway...

Comment: @jeroen - That is true. I'd add the global declaration to round it out. I still much prefer the second function to using global variables.

Comment: @Jon - Really? If a variable doesn't exist until the function is called with the global keyword, it will automatically create global variables by those names?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes. Have you tried it? There's nothing surprising in it -- you just tell the compiler "put these variables up in global scope". There is no magic reason they need to be *already* in global scope.

Comment: @Jon - Interesting. No, I haven't.

Comment: No, it doesn´t work. I just saw a question about that a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462229/php-newbie-question-global-variables-for-web/5462265#5462265

Comment: @jeroen: I don't know why you think that, maybe this will change your mind? http://ideone.com/nay96

Comment: Well, the poster of the question I mentioned (using global did not work) and the php manual: `By declaring $a and $b global within the function, all references to either variable will refer to the global version.`. But pretty sure can still be wrong :-)

Comment: @jeroen: Don't trust the poster of any question more than the compiler. And the manual reference sure does *not* say it won't work.

Comment: @jeroen - You're telling me... :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your variables in your function as global.

Comment: This is misleading. The variables need to actually be declared "in global scope" and then accessed using the `global` keyword within the function, according to this answer. However, DO NOT THIS. It is not necessary. Wait for Jon's answer, he'll get you fixed up.

Comment: @Callum: DONT do that... return an array of the values you need like `return array('days' => $days, 'hours' => $hours, 'mins' => $minutes);` Or if you dont need to modify the format of the string your outputting just return the string you want to echo form the function.

Comment: Add global in front of your variables in your function, which you use outside this function.

Comment: You are right, see Jon's comment on his answer. However, it's still far less than the best solution to the problem, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning `$days`, `$hours` or `$minutes` from the function.

```
<?php

list($days,$hours,$minutes) = countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);

function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
$the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
$today=time();
$difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
$days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
return array($days,$hours,$minutes);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo "$days days $hours hours $minutes minutes";?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
$the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
$today=time();
$difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
$days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
$hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
$minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
return $days.' days '.$hours.' hours '.$minutes.' minutes';
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);?></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In all respect, this makes the function *less* useful, so it's not a good solution.

Comment: I don't want to argue, but consider: this way, the function can only do *one* thing (return a string). Otherwise (if it returns three numbers), you can then use them in any way you might find useful.

Comment: @jon well that's a guess on your part that the output may be required in another format, i guessed it wouldn't be, its up to the op which is *right*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line of the function countdown() to return the correct string ("$days days etc.") and then making the embedded line of php code

`<h1><?php echo countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);
?></h1>`

Comment: This will not work, the function doesn't return the string that's to be output

Comment: I mentioned to change it so that it does (in the first half of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said you cant access the variables in the function.  A way around this is to have the function return something.

```
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute){
    $the_countdown_date=mktime($hour, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year, -1);
    $today=time();
    $difference=$the_countdown_date - $today;
    $days=floor($difference/60/60/24);
    $hours=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24)/60/60);
    $minutes=floor(($difference - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/60);
    return array(
        'days' => $days,
        'hours' => $hours,
        'minutes' => $minutes
    );
}

$cd = countdown(2011,6,7,7,31,0);

<?php echo $days ?> days <?php echo $hours ?> hours <?php echo $minutes ?> minutes
```